# Visual Studio Community 2015 Auto Complete Options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

So, in visual studio 2015 when I am typing, options come up for auto complete. Problem is, when none of those options match, and I type dot ('.'), it auto completes to the first option. I end up having to press ESC to go back which is actually annoying.

For instance, If I type:

Sys

Options come up that include:

- System
- SystemException
- OperatingSystem

If I actually have my own class called Sys, and I want to reference its members such as Sys.getId() or so, when I type:

Sys.

Visual studio actually inserts,

System.

I'd like to change it so it doesn't complete on the dot (.), but only autocompletes on space or tab key. Is that possible? because this is annoying as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Edit -> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode
```

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Now I can press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the recommended member (`System`), but if I need `Sys.Test` I can just do `Sys` and then `.`